# How do you use an Ampersand in an HTTPCookie in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, cookies, ampersand

I have a cookie saved to the user as follows...

```
Dim searchCookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("SearchCriteria")
searchCookie.Item("SearchText") = FullSearchCriteria.SearchText
searchCookie.Item("SearchType") = FullSearchCriteria.SearchType
```

The SearchText stores a value they have input in a previous page. We have observed if there is an ampersand in the cookie (eg Tyne & Wear), then the cookie doesn't save subsequent values (SearchType).

What happens is the cookie is output like this:

```
SearchText=Tyne &
```

Obviously the ampersand is confusing the cookie. Is there a way to prevent this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [URLEncode](http://www.liquidjelly.co.uk/supersearch/?q=msdn%20URLEncode&lang=en-GB) method.

Something like:

```
imports HttpContext.Current
...
Dim searchCookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("SearchCriteria")
searchCookie.Item("SearchText") = Server.UrlEncode(FullSearchCriteria.SearchText)
searchCookie.Item("SearchType") = Server.UrlEncode(FullSearchCriteria.SearchType)
```

This is essential as [only certain characters are allowed in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies) with characters such as [ampersands breaking them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125807/broken-string-in-cookie-after-ampersand-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

D'oh! I'm such a dork...

```
Dim searchCookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("SearchCriteria")
searchCookie.Item("SearchText") = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(FullSearchCriteria.SearchText)
searchCookie.Item("SearchType") = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(FullSearchCriteria.SearchType)
```

Answer (score 1):

The cookie values need to be encoded. I'm no VB expert, but it looks like this is done with the method

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode
```