# putting ='s, ampersands and colons in a cookie

Tags: http, cookies, urlencode, session-cookies, httpcookie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allowed characters in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies)

I need to separate values in a cookie.  So I chose &'s to separate name=value pairs just like I would in a URL.  There can be multiple values too for a name, so I separate those with a colon.

My question is if this is legal?  Do I need to URL encode everything?  The values can have colons inside them, so I thought I'd URL encode the values in order to make sure the colons in a value don't conflict with the separator character.  I read somewhere that enclosing the entire cookie with apostrophes works too, does that make sense?

If this is not legal, what's the best way to store my multiple name/value pairs that often have multiple values per name (in a specific order, so I can't just duplicate the name/values)?

Comment: Is there a reason you’re not using one cookie per name/value pair?

Comment: I guess 2 reasons, but neither are very important... so I'm certainly open to changing that and doing away with the &s.  First, there might be many name/value pairs and I don't want to inundate someone monitoring their cookies and risk problems there.  Secondly, it just makes for easier processing in JavaScript... all I have to do is $.each(cookie.split('&'), ...

Comment: Duplicate of [Allowed characters in cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies). I couldn't answer better than Bobince already did. By the way, I'd investigate if utilizing the server side session isn't a better approach since cookies are pretty limited in the amount of information they can hold.

Comment: You could encrypt the data before storing it in the cookie, then, you save any values you want.

Comment: @BalusC - Bobince did in fact give a great response, thanks.  @James Black - what is the best way to encrypt data in a cookie?  Base64?  simple URL Encode?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to percent-escape the characters contained in the name and value parts of the cookie, just like you should already be doing.  For example, `=` would become `%3D`, `&` would become `%26`, etc.  Just build up the string you want to use for your cookie value and run it through your language/framework's URI escaping function.  If your framework has a method for setting cookies and it takes distinct name/value arguments, it *should* be doing this for you.

Comment: My framework is Spring 3/JEE 6 and they do not, according to the JavaDoc I'm reading, escape or unescape cookies at all.

Comment: Then you will have to do what I've suggested and use a URI escaping function on the name and value prior to sending it to the browser.