# Jquery stop HTML encoding cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, escaping, html-encode

I'm using this short snippet of code:

```
var d = itemID + "," + quantity;
var CookieData = $.cookie("storebasket");

if(CookieData == null || CookieData == "") {
    $.cookie("storebasket", d, { path: '/', expires: 60 });
} else {
    $.cookie("storebasket", CookieData + "|" + d, { path: '/', expires: 60 });
}
```

However the value ALWAYS becomes HTML encoded.  For example:

```
5%2C1
```

Which when decoded [with this tool](http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/entitydecode.php) is:

```
5,1
```

I've tried using `unescape` but no luck:

```
$.cookie("storebasket", unescape(d), { path: '/', expires: 60 });
```

Any more ideas?

Comment: Weird. Unescape works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9LdxL/

Comment: @Jonny, that Fiddle works but when we try and save it into a Cookie the value is always HTML encoded

Answer (score 13):

jquery.cookie is encoding the comma by default. To override this just do:

```
$.cookie.raw = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is really useful:

[Allowed characters in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies)

But I really don't see the problem. When you want to use them in your document, you can unescape them. If you want to store them in the cookies, they are being escaped.

Comment: The problem is is that if Javascript is disabled the site falls back to it's non JS version.  The server side cookie setting doesn't HTML encode the data, so when JS decides to encode it we don't know server side whether it needs decoding or not.

Comment: What if you always decode it on the server side? As far as I know, a decoded string stays the same when you decode it.

Comment: It might not be safe to do that in every case, for example if we want to store `%20` as a value

Comment: Ok. What about using another character than comma, that gets not encoded? Only comma, white-space and semicolon are disallowed.

Comment: It's a possible idea, but it's more of a hack that could raise problems in the future.  The best way to solve this problem is by making it store the value in the cookie in a non HTML encoded way.  It will also be more confusing and time consuming to modify for anyone else who has to maintain it in the future as well

Comment: What about base64 encoding the cookie and then decode it afterwards on the server? Even YouTube does use base64 encoding in cookies. All base64 characters don't get urlencoded.

Comment: I agree that Tom Gullen has a real issue. I'm trying to create a cookie for a third-party script to read. Since I can't control their script, just choosing how to decode the cookie is not an option.