# Create cookie containing ";" character

Tags: java, cookies

I want to create a cookie that it's value contains many ";" characters that is usually used to separate multiple cookies in java, that's why my code isn't making his job. 
if someone can help me how to create this "special" cookie and make my code work?
thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use URL encoding to escape any special characters (`+`, `%`, `=`, `;`).

The URL encoded value of `;` is `%3B`.

For a better reference, check out the [Java JSON API](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/Cookie.html#escape%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: it didn't work, same problem, isn't there any class in java to create cookies one by one?

Answer (score 4):

Semicolon [is not allowed in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969339/373151). Your best shot is to use some other separator. Read the linked answer to figure out what character can be used.

Comment: I actually have a cookie that contains some Semicolons, even if it is forbidden, i have to create one cookie with that value, isn't there a way to encode the cookie or somthing so that the Semicolons in it's value don't make the separation in it?