# How can I store a style value in a cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Hi,

I have html like this:

```
<div id="myelm" style="color:black;font-weight:bold;">
```

I want to store the style value in a cookie like this:

```
setCookie('mystyle', myelm.getAttribute('style'));
```

however only the part before the first semicolon is stored, ignoring all the rest. How can I bypass that?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create cookie containing ";" character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349155/create-cookie-containing-character)

Comment: No, it DOESNT answer my question. How come I am supposed to take the semicolon out if thats the correct syntaxis for a css declaration??

Comment: It does answer your question. You replace all semicolons with `%3B` and it says why in the linked question.