# jQuery: JSON.stringify changes my object value after saving in cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, stringify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allowed characters in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies)

I'm using `JSON.stringify` to convert an object to save it in a cookie. But after saving Arabic Windows-1256 encoding in a cookie, I wasn't able to restore it. Here's what I did:

For example:

Convert and save in a cookie.

```
conv[user]   = {"user":1,"u":1,"m":3,"c":255,"comment":'السلام عليكم ورحمه الله'};
addCookie('chat_conversations', JSON.stringify(conv) , 7);
```

Restore value from cookie:

```
var con  = is_cookie('chat_conversations');
conv = jQuery.parseJSON(con);
```

Getting my JSON result:

```
alert(conv[1].comment);
```

Result

> "'D3D'E 9DJCE H1-EG 'DDG H(1C'*G\n"

Here's the result of my cookie

> chat_conversations={"1":{"user":"1","u":"1","m":3,"c":255,"comment":"'D3D'E 9DJCE H1-EG 'DDG H(1C'*G\n"}}; expires=Sat, 08 Dec 2012 15:00:42 GMT; path=/; domain=127.0.0.1

How can I save an object containing Arabic in a cookie and restore it?

Comment: Well, I'll be honest. I just used your code in my Localhost and I cannot replicate this issue; Although< I didn't use windows-1256, I used UTF-8.

Comment: Check when exactly did you encode your string to windows-1256. JSON uses UTF-8 by default, so maybe you'll have to do extra work to encode/decode.

Comment: + take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies

Comment: Use `escape` on the string which isn't working as expected and `unescape` when retrieving it.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy , My encoding is 'utf-8' but the Arabic characters are 'windows-1256' encode , it work fine for english but not with arabic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sanatise strings going into a cookie using `escape` or `encodeURIComponent` (minor differences between the two, see below) and then reverse this via `unescape` or `decodeURICompontent` when retrieving the data.

```
// Create obj using safe chars only
conv[user] = {
    "user" : 1, // (numbers are fine as they are)
    "u" : 1,
    "m" : 3,
    "c" : 255,
    "comment" : escape('السلام عليكم ورحمه الله') // by escaping potentially unsafe chars
};
// save
addCookie('chat_conversations', JSON.stringify(conv) , 7);
// retrieve
var con  = is_cookie('chat_conversations');
conv = jQuery.parseJSON(con);

var comment = unescape(conv[1].comment); // unescape what was escaped earlier
alert(comment);
// "السلام عليكم ورحمه الله"
```

`escape` is fine because you just want to use this data in JavaScript. If you want to access the cookie server-side then I'd strongly recommend using `encodeURIComponent`.

If you are just using it for JavaScript, consider `window.localStorage` because it will cause less internet usage.