# Can HTTP cookie name contain dashes?

Tags: php, http, session, cookies, browser

Can HTTP cookie name contain dashes?
Any reliable reference?

I've tried on Chrome and it's fine but I'm scared that other browsers may not allow because in PHP reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php says:

```
name:
The session name references the name of the session, 
which is used in cookies and URLs (e.g. PHPSESSID). 
***It should contain only alphanumeric characters;***
```

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1969339/589909 or here http://www.uvsc.edu/disted/decourses/mct/2760/IN/krutscjo/lessons/10/dp_04.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowed characters in cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies)

Comment: the only issue with the rules, is that every browser can do as it likes, we all know browsers see the same html differently. if your worried- then simply don't use them (-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A cookie name is defined as a 'token' within the parlance of the defining [RFC6265](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc6265.html). A token is defined in [RFC2616](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) Section 2.2. Here's the extract:

```
   token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>
   separators     = "(" | ")" | "<" | ">" | "@"
                  | "," | ";" | ":" | "\" | <">
                  | "/" | "[" | "]" | "?" | "="
                  | "{" | "}" | SP | HT
```

As you see, a dash ("-") doesn't appear in the list, so it's OK.

Comment: +1 for pointing to a Standards document. I prefer linking directly to the IETF's html formatted RFC pages, though, where you can also link to concrete subsections: [RFC6265, 4.1.1 Syntax](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.1).

Answer (score 6):

The spec says yes, my experience says no.

Using Chromium on Ubuntu, I developed a very odd problem with hyphens in cookies today which brought me to this question.  Using a hyphen was causing the cookie to expire within microseconds (proven by dumping document.cookie to the console several times in the page load).

After tearing most of my hair out, I can clearly see now that

```
tibbed-WP_ID_313=true; expires=Wed, 03 Dec 2014 20:28:26 GMT
```

(two days away) lasts for about half way through the page load, whereas these variants

```
tibbedWP_ID_313=true; 
tibbed_WP_ID_313=true; 
tibbed:WP_ID_313=true;
```

all persist as they should.

This code has been working fine for the past couple of months.  Go figure.  I will be avoiding hyphens (dashes) from now on.

Comment: Currently having this issue, when using hyphens there are odd undocumented behaviours. By switching to camel case everything works as expected. Could not find information about this issue anywhere else