# Javascript: Problems parsing document.cookie JSON object

Tags: javascript, django, json, cookies

On the server I'm storing a JSON object as a cookie (using Django / json.dumps), it looks like so:

```
'{"name": "Simon", "gender": "M"}'
```

On the client when I run document.cookie I can see the cookie and it looks like so:

```
"user="{\"name\": \"Simon\"\054 \"gender\": \"M\"}";
```

I have a small function which retrieves a cookie by name ( getCookie('user') )it returns a string:

```
"{\"name\": \"Simon\"\054 \"gender\": \"M\"}"
```

I want to parse this back to a JSON object for further use on the client however JSON.parse() returns the error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected number".

Whats strange is if you run the following:

```
JSON.parse("{\"name\": \"Simon\"\054 \"gender\": \"M\"}")
```

directly in the console it works fine. Any ideas?

If there is a better way to store the cookie etc im open to ideas

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `\054` doing there?

Comment: you can't insert comma in a Cookie because are alreay a separator inside cookie logic, so:
`'{\"name\": \"Simon\"\054 \"gender\": \"M\"}'.replace("\054",",");` first.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `\054` is breaking your json. it's a encoded `,` (comma).

This:

```
string.replace(/\\054/g, ',');
```

should probably do it.

Comment: the \ wont replace, when I try string.replace('\054', ',') I get back the same string

Comment: backslash not ment to be replaced, try double back-slash \\

Comment: +1 as you are correct the \054 was breaking the JSON, now just to figure out why i cant replace it :/

Comment: my bad... for the ease of asking the question i only show 2 items in the JSON, in reality there is a lot of data. Your answer is correct however it just replaced a single instance of \054. 

str.replace(/\\054/g, ",") did the trick thanks for your help

Comment: I'll add that to the answer :) Glad to be of some help.

Answer (score 8):

Comma is an illegal character in Cookie... and is not the only one, for prevent problem maybe you can encode your JSON befoure put in cookie:

```
encodeURIComponent('{"name": "Simon", "gender": "M"}');
//return "%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Simon%22%2C%20%22gender%22%3A%20%22M%22%7D"

decodeURIComponent('%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Simon%22%2C%20%22gender%22%3A%20%22M%22%7D');
//return '{"name": "Simon", "gender": "M"}'
```

This answer explains better the world of "allowed character" in cookie:
[Allowed characters in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies)

:) i hope it can help...

Comment: +1 for the info on 'allowed cookies', i was hoping to create something on the server that i could easily parse as JSON on the client, Python is not making it easy