# Cookie encryption oddness

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So, I am using a cookie to store some basic data. All works fine.
Now, I want to encrypt the cookie data. I am using TripleDES encryption (192). This works fine but one of the requirements is to encrypt the entire data in one big long string - later on when reading, will have to manually parse out the values after decrypting - that's ok.

The odd problem is that, when I encrypt the name value and then set the encrypted value to it, next time I read it on a DIFFERENT request (i.e button click), it does not find the key/name! I look in the object visualizer and see that the name indeed is slightly different than what I had originally assigned it:

// save

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
var encryptedName = MySecurityHelper.TripleDES.Encrypt("UserInfo");
var encryptedData = MySecurityHelper.TripleDES.Encrypt("Id:1[]Name:Joe"); // [] is the delimiter
cookie[encryptedName] = encryptedData;
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

// read

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies["MyCookie"];
var encryptedName = MySecurityHelper.TripleDES.Encrypt("UserInfo");
var decryptedData = MySecurityHelper.TripleDES.Decrypt(cookie[encryptedName]);
```

any ideas why?

so when saving, the cookie name value could be:
FzgGr1=

but then after when interrogating the cookie object, its FzgGr1

any ideas why it would be different on the subsequent request? Totally weird and unexplainable.

Comment: Any reason you are using a really out dated Encryption algorithm?

Comment: Maybe a browser treats the = character as a delimiter and therefore doesn't preserve it?

Comment: What is `MySecurityHelper`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers send cookies to server along with request headers. And there are several reserved characters('**=**','**;**','**&**'), which should be avoided in cookie name or value.

[W3C Specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109)

Try this,

```
cookie[System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encryptedName)] = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encryptedData);
```

[image: Screenshot of this page's request header]
[Screenshot of this page's request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOTBY.png)

**EDIT :** [Allowed characters in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies)