# What is cookie allowed characters in modern/nowadays browsers?

Tags: http, cookies, httpcookie

What is cookie **allowed characters** in **modern/nowadays** browsers if you use cookies to **encode utf-8 string** or binary informations?

I found some answer on StackOverflow from 2009 year but it is obsolete and refer to modern browsers at all since after 5 years things are changing.

I study already theory - less or more:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie
2. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965
3. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265
4. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109
5. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616

How it looks in practice in modern:

1. Chrome
2. Firefox
3. Safari
4. IE (XP, Win7, Win8)
5. Opera
6. Android/iOS

Can you suggest what characters should be used?

What encoding should be used (base64?)?

Comment: The cookie spec has not changed at all so data from 2009 is still relevant. Also, the cookie _spec_ is completely independent of browsers.

Comment: I am sure that spec from 2009 is still relevant but it not mean that modern browsers will not support utf8 without encodings to base64 or use urlencode methods.

Answer (score 0):

Valid characters in cookie for browser has not changed. What is mentioned in [allowed-characters-in-cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies) is still valid.

But with a recent experience of JBoss upgrade, I would suggest URLEncode the base64 string and use it as cookie value. Reason being `=` is control character as per spec. Discussed and debated in detail at [TomcatBugzilla-44679](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44679).

Comment: Maybe it is internal JBoss bug - since all comes as http headers. Thanks for suggestion - I am using some slang base64 what is waste of bytes but very sure. I read response to this old answer but it is not clear as this internet standard.