# ExpressJS unicode cookie

Tags: javascript, unicode, express

Is there any way to send unicode values in a cookie in expressjs. When a user is using a Spanish locale, a cookie is serialized with the user name, which can be something like "José"

e.g:

```
 res.cookie('user', JSON.stringify({name: 'José'}));
```

However in the client I get a cookie with the value:

```
{name: 'JosÃ©'}
```

is there any way around this? The server already outputs that.

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I will create an issue in the express github page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use unicode characters in a cookie, you should use an encoding scheme.

encodeURIComponent() or querystring.escape() in node when setting the cookie and decodeURIComponent() in the client should work.

It's not specific to express, but how cookies work in general.
See this answer for details: [Allowed characters in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969339/5235655)