# Space in cookie name causes api to return 401

Tags: asp.net, cookies, http-headers

We just started adding the authorize attribute to our api endpoints. Everything was working fine until we put these changes into our test environment.  When ANY cookie has a space in the name it causes the api to kick back a 401.  I was wondering if anyone had this same issue or if there was some way to either fix the cookie or api?

Comment: I don't think spaces are allowed in cookie name http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies

Comment: They are not, but I don't have any control over our customers creating bad cookies.  I am looking for a way to handle this.  I was thinking about running a check and deleting any bad cookies.  But I was hoping there was a better way.  I HATE the idea of deleting anything, especially when I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was returning a 401 was the get cookies method was returning null.

```
 HttpRequestHeaders.GetCookies("COOKIENAME");
```

So even though that cookie existed. If ANY cookie had a space (or invalid char) in the name it would cause that method to return null.  In the case you are using this in a filter (in our case a MembershipAuthorization) then you will have to access the cookies in different way.  I am not happy about it, but I used a string split on semicolon.  Which isn't guarenteed because if the value is not urlencoded then there could be a semicolon that would throw this off.

```
 var cookiesString = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("Cookie").First();            
        try
        {
            foreach (var cook in cookiesString.Split(';'))
            {
                if (cook.Split('=').First().ToUpper().Trim() == "COOKIENAME")
                {
                    currentUser = cook.Split('=')[1];
                }
            }
        }
```