# Why does HttpServletRequest#getCookies returns null for cookie with colon value?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, jboss

When sending a header with the value `Cookie: c=:`, the servlet implementation of JBoss 7.2.0.Final returns `null` for the following code:

```
request.getCookies(); // null
```

But when I read the header it returns the value correctly:

```
request.getHeader( "Cookie" ); // c=:
```

According to the [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1), colon should be considered a valid cookie-value. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969339/1400037) shows the proper characters inside the allowed range (see the colon right there in the third line).

Now, can somebody tell me why the hell the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest#getCookies()` implementation of JBoss 7.2.0.final cannot read a cookie created with `:` in the value?

Comment: if that's the case, it can be considered a bug in JBoss, and you should file a bug report.

Comment: Before you leap to the conclusion that it is a JBoss bug, you ought to take a look at the raw header line, and see if there are 1) extraneous whitespace characters, 2) homoglyphs or 3) something else unexpected.

Comment: I can ensure that there's no additional whitespace/homoglyphs or anything else unexpected. I have an integration test that checks the encoding routine for all allowed and disallowed cookie characters. When I changed the code to read from the "Cookie" header the character is processed correctly. Take a look in the project that is in development: https://github.com/js-cookie/java-cookie/tree/c157e41f3b1c0412577333cd7b92083976f02ba6

Comment: It fails for the following test: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/61abed8ffbb48eaf53e31219495ccba215e4d8f2/test/encoding.js#L122-L130. A lot of other tests with different characters failed with the same symptom, but after fixing the colon problem by reading directly from the header, it solved most of them.