# Lumen/Laravel session for specific route

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am trying to get working Lumen session but only for a specific route, since on other I don't need it.

All I find is to enable middlewhere like

```
$app->middleware([
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
]);
```

(source https://stackoverflow.com/a/32635502/1861519)

But this will do a global session setting. But I needed it only as sad on specific route.

Comment: You can specify middleware directly on the route like:
$app->get('/', ['middleware' => 'yourMiddleware', 'uses' => 'Your/Controller@method'])

Answer (score 0):

> All app level middleware goes here

```
  $app->middleware([
     \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies,
     \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse ]);
```

> Custom middleware that need session

$app->routeMiddleware([
   'session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession]);

> Now add it in route

```
$app->get('/protected', ['middleware' => 'session', 'uses' => 'ProtectedController@index'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this when use session on specific routes:

```
$session = $request->session();
$session->put('foo', 'bar');
echo $session->get('foo');
$session->save();
```

`save()` will persist the session file for you.