# Validation of signed cookie fails with request lib

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

Our signed cookies implementation works in Firefox, Chrome and IE.

We use the [requests library](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for testing.

For some reason the request library seem to alter the cookie data.

We use session like in the docs: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

Any idea why the library changes the cookie data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all characters are allowed inside a cookie.

See https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/286

The library `requests` alters the data.

A solution might be to store the cookie data base64 encoded.

Related: [Allowed characters in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies)