# Using cookies to pass URL param string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I have a URL which contains a '!' in the value of a query parameter.  I enocode the param string in cookies and load a related page.  From php:

```
foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ){
    setcookie($key,$value,time()+60,'/');
}
```

In the related page, the value of the cookie (read through  javascript/jquery $.cookie("")) has the '!' encoded as %21.

Can someone tell me why the '!' has been encoded?  Isn't it a valid character in a cookie value?

Comment: on front end you can use the `decodeURIComponent('%21')` which equals `!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two places that the data may be encoded. The first, is when it is fetched from the `$_GET` array, the `$value` may be encoded, and may be decoded by using `rawurldecode()`. The second place that encoding may occur is when using `setcookie()`; to avoid this, use `setrawcookie()` instead, which will set the raw cookie instead of an encoded cookie.

```
foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ){
    setrawcookie($key, rawurldecode($value), time() + 60, '/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone tell me why the '!' has been encoded? Isn't it a valid character in a cookie value?

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969339/1400037). According to the the RFC 6265, `!` is a valid character in the cookie name and value. If php is encoding `!` it means that it is a bug.

To fix this you can do what @Andrew suggested or use a library called [js-cookie](http://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) that allows intercepting the cookie reading using [converters](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/v2.1.0#converters), then you can revert the encoding that PHP does in the client.