# Play Framework2.2 cookie

Tags: java, playframework

I'm Japanese.
I'm using Play Framework2.2.
I use cookie like this.

```
public class AppController extends Application {
   public static Result index() {

      response().setCookie("myName",  "くっきー"); //Japanese String
      return ok(index.render());
   }

   public static Result result() {
      response().setCookie("myName",  "くっきー"); //Japanese String
      //garbled characters
      return ok(request().cookie("myName").value());
   }
}
```

But, value is garbled characters.

if I use java.net.URLEncoder, I succeeded in saving and extract Japanese String. But I wonder Play Framework has a more useful solution?

Comment: Are you using UTF encoding?

Comment: yes URLEncoder.encode("くっきー","UTF-8") and URLDecoder.decode(request().cookie("myName").value(),"UTF-8")

Comment: I don't think you can use Japanese characters in cookies (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies).