# Printing Javascript Cookie in PHP with plus sign

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, escaping, special-characters

I am assigning the javascript value to php but plus sign is not exist in output after printing  and cannot escape it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.cookie = "mydata =index.php?test=1+test2=1";
</script>

<?php 
   $myPHPdata =  $_COOKIE['mydata'];

   echo $myPHPdata;
?>
```

Getting this output without plus sign(+) => `"index.php?test=1 test2=1"` plus is mssign

How can i print plus sign too ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this. It will work.

```
var plus = encodeURIComponent('+');
document.cookie = "mydata=index.php?test=1"+ plus +"test2=1";
```