# French content does not get stored in cookie only with Safari in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, safari

Other browsers are giving the results as expected but the problem is only with Safari.
When we have a french text like **Créer** it does not store the value in the cookie.

### Step 01

Storing the values in cookie as follow

```
CookieStudent.Values["FirstName"] = newApplicant.FirstName;
CookieStudent.Values["LastName"] = newApplicant.LastName; 
CookieStudent.Values["Email"] = newApplicant.Email;
CookieStudent.Values["BirthDate"] = newApplicant.DateOfBirth;
Response.Cookies.Add(CookieStudent);
```

### Step 02

Getting the stored cookie value from another controller.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CookieStudent.Values["FirstName"]))
{
   newApplicant.FirstName = CookieStudent.Values["FirstName"];
}
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CookieStudent.Values["LastName"])) 
{
   newApplicant.LastName = CookieStudent.Values["LastName"];
}
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CookieStudent.Values["Email"]))
{
   newApplicant.Email = CookieStudent.Values["Email"];
}
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CookieStudent.Values["BirthDate"]))
{
   newApplicant.DateOfBirth = CookieStudent.Values["BirthDate"];
}
```

**Note : This solution was not working for me** `Server.HtmlEncode(newApplicant.FirstName); or HttpUtility.UrlEncode(newApplicant.FirstName); and then corresponding decode`

Comment: Please show us how `CookieStudent` is declared. Also, please include a screenshot of your cookie values (something like https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/see_full_cookie_details_in_safari_5.1 ).

Comment: have you check with Creer without the accent on the e?

Comment: Can you show us what you used to decode after using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`?

Comment: @CedricRoyer-Bertrand I can not prevent that. Yes it works without that accent in Safari but this is a site which supports English and French so when it comes to french there are situations where these kind of accents are in use.

Comment: @mjwills This is how decode is done. HttpUtility.UrlDecode(CookieStudent.Values["FirstName"]);

Comment: `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` should work. Can you show us a screenshot of your cookie values when you use that?

Comment: @mjwills Finally HttpUtility.UrlEncode and HttpUtility.UrlDecode worked for me in Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two changes resolved the problem with Safari browser for french characters

For Encode    `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(newApplicant.FirstName);` 
and for decode `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(CookieStudent.Values["FirstName"]);`

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread [allowed character in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies) it could be because of the **é**. Try maybe to not use accent in your code, and only use them when you want to display something for the user.