# An invalid character [59] was present in the Cookie value

Tags: java, tomcat, cookies

So I have seen other questions about this, but none have been able to solve my issue.

I am getting a

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid character [59] was present in the Cookie value
```

error.  I am using DeviceLookupClient.jar and it adds a cookie somewhere that tomcat is refusing.

So when I run this in weblogic after everything is successful I get this cookie (from network tab):

```
WurflCloud_Client   
value   "{\"capabilities\":{\"is_smart…383,\"id\":\"firefox_54_0\"}"
expires "2017-08-17T16:03:03.000Z"
```

Run the same code in tomcat and it fails before that cookie ever gets created.  I believe [59] character is a semicolon and I don't see any in there.  If something in that cookie is not allowed then is there a way to allow it, rather than manipulate the library I am using?

Comment: If you check out this question it also says commas aren't allowed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies Could it be that it has a problem with the comma and is throwing a false error that you have a semicolon?

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the comment. That's interesting, I am going to try a few things and see if I can replicate the error using a comma in the cookie on another page

Comment: So no matter what I do it works on my LOCAL tomcat server and every instance of my weblogic server.

Comment: Maybe your remote server is configured slightly differently than your local server? In that case you'd have to do more research on that I'm not familiar with tomcat server setup

Answer (score 2):

It might be solved if you encode the given value like this:

```
URLEncoder.encode(""{\"capabilities\":{\"is_smart…383,\"id\":\"firefox_54_0\"}"","UTF-8");
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that would fix it, but unfortunately the cookie is added deep within the library (DeviceLookupClient.jar) I am using.  I guess I could change it and rejar it, but we usually don't do that.