# Safari cookie value strips space after the commas

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari

I am trying to set a session cookie to save an Address. Every time I save the cookie that contains comma followed by space, Safari strips out the space after the commas and breaks the format.

```
// JavaScript code to save the cookie
document.cookie = "Address=Sample Address, Ontario, Canada;path=/;expire=0;";

// Result
document.cookie => "Address=Sample Address,Ontario,Canada"
```

Is there any solution to this behaviour? Can we somehow tell Safari not to strip the spaces?

*Safari Version 10.1.2 (12603.3.8) | MacOS Sierra Version 10.12.6*

Comment: Notice how it preserved your first space but removed all after it.  I am seeing behavior more as "only the first space is preserved."  This detail is really odd and very safari specific in my testing.

Comment: The spaces or equals sign in the payload for Safari is different than all other browsers.   I UrlEncoded my cookie payload on set and urldecoded on read.  That fixed safari.  This next post was Extremely Helpful.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found and solved is by UriEncoding the value of the cookie you are trying to set. And decoding the same when you are reading the value of the cookie.