# Setting cookie in Angular gets encoded

Tags: cookies, character, angular8

I am setting a cookie in the Angular app using the CookieService from "ngx-cookie-service".  Some of the characters involved in the cookie get converted into different characters when retrieved at the server-side. I wish to stop this behavior of character conversion

This is a new problem for me as I have been trying to achieve this very recently and I am very new to Angular.

```
public ngOnInit(): void{

  this.cookieService.set('SMSESSION', '4vsKaqcVTzGOr9PTG4JV05s52OLYDjMIriTnYDbIHCKYocP0wcXBtmzojEkL2VzCPdMRNg4osirJKfJMSQT7fv29MsIfYBxhQSxU+GKO/');

  }
}
```

I expected the output  to be like this:

```
4vsKaqcVTzGOr9PTG4JV05s52OLYDjMIriTnYDbIHCKYocP0wcXBtmzojEkL2VzCPdMRNg4osirJKfJMSQT7fv29MsIfYBxhQSxU`+`GKO`/`
```

But it gets converted like this

```
4vsKaqcVTzGOr9PTG4JV05s52OLYDjMIriTnYDbIHCKYocP0wcXBtmzojEkL2VzCPdMRNg4osirJKfJMSQT7fv29MsIfYBxhQSxU`%2B`GKO`%2F`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cookie is getting URL encoded.  It should also be automatically decoded if you try to read it.  Please take a look at this similar posting [Should cookie values be URL encoded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205195/should-cookie-values-be-url-encoded).

Comment: The link provided in the response helped. So there is specific characters that cannot be set in cookie when we use "ngx-cookie-service" of Angular. This service encodes those characters and hence it needs to be decoded from server side.