# ampersand(&) replaced by %26 value in Cookies

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js

`ampersand(&)` replaced by %26 value.

I set the cookie value TEST&123&223 in code, but in a browser, cookie value replaced by TEST%26123%26223.

I am trying to set cookie value in angular code.  I have used third party library 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service.

Is there a way to tell the browser, don't decode the string value in cookies?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should encode your data before storing it (In JavaScript it would be `encodeURI('&')` however if you use some other language on your server it could be different command but the idea stays the same).

Then you should decode cookie (`decodeURI(string)`) when reading the value.

Answer (score 0):

The browser does not have anything to do with your issue : TEST%26123%26223 is an encoded value. It's the 3rd party library you're using that is encoding the value of your cookie.

```
    let cookieString: string = encodeURIComponent( name ) + '=' + encodeURIComponent( value ) + ';';
```

(extracted from library's github repository : https://github.com/7leads/ngx-cookie-service/blob/master/lib/cookie-service/cookie.service.ts)

Encoding cookie value is not a bad thing, it is actually recommended : [Should cookie values be URL encoded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205195/should-cookie-values-be-url-encoded)
If you want to retrieve the original value you'll need to decode it (the library you use is decoding the cookie value in the get function).