# How to pass json encode into cookie in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, cookies

When im check JSON encode with print_r it look fine => `{"expiry":1636191448,"auth":true}`

Then im try to store it inside cookie,
but it turn into like this when i see it in browser cookies value => `%7B%22expiry%22%3A1636191866%2C%22auth%22%3Atrue%7D`

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix it. Im not use this for permission system, but for other thing like read it in javascript but i got error when try to parse it

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0
> at JSON.parse ()

.

This are the line of code in my php file

```
if (Cookie::exists(Config::get('client/cookie_name'))) {
    $client = json_decode(Cookie::get(Config::get('client/cookie_name')), true);
    $expiry = $client['expiry'];
} else {
    $client = array (
        'expiry' => time() + Config::get('client/cookie_expiry')
    );
}

$client['auth'] = true;

$client = json_encode($client);
Cookie::update(Config::get('client/cookie_name'), $client, $expiry);
```

Comment: Please post relevant code. How exactly are you storing the JSON data as a cookie? The second string is the JSON string in url encoded format, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are often URL-encoded (but sometimes different encodings are used). Since this isn't really standardized and by spec there is only a handful of characters that must be encoded *somehow* (not specified how), different systems may take different routes in handling cookie encoding, and therefore reading cookies set by one system using another system can cause issues like these.

In your case, you can call `decodeURIComponent` on the value first:

```js
const json = decodeURIComponent(encodedCookieValue)
const data = JSON.parse(json)
```

Further reading: [Should cookie values be URL encoded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205195/should-cookie-values-be-url-encoded)

Comment: (By the way, because this type of encoding is often used, devtools offer you to show the decoded value too - just tick the box "Show URL decoed" that is visible in your screenshot.)