# Why do I have to decodeURIComponent the cookie in my session in order for it to work with passport & express-session?

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, passport.js, express-session

I've recently been building a social media app and I'm using Next.js app router on the client-side with express-session cookie-based auth and passport.

The way that my server-side code is structured is the following:

index.ts

```
app.use(helmet());
app.use(limiter);
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  session({
    store: redisStore,
    secret: process.env.REDIS_SECRET || "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    proxy: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? false : true,
    name: "_session",
    cookie: {
      sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "none" : "none",
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? false : true,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1,
      httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? false : true,
      path: "/",
      domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "localhost:3000" : "",
    },
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

authMiddleware.ts

```
export const authUser = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
    return;
  }

  return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: "Unauthorized" });
};
```

passport serialize & desereliaze

```
passport.serializeUser<any, any>((user: User, done: any) => {
  const safeUser: SafeUser = {
    id: user.id,
    email: user.email,
    name: user.name,
    bio: user.bio,
    image: user.image,
    googleId: user.googleId,
    appleId: user.appleId,
  };

  done(null, safeUser);
});

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
passport.deserializeUser<any, any>((user: User, done: any) => {
  done(null, user);
});
```

route example

```
router.get('/search/:search/', authUser, async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
 const userData = req.user as SafeUser;
 const email = userData.email
 try {
  const categories = await findMatchedCategory(req.params.search, email)
  res.json(categories);
 } catch (error) {
  next(error);
 }
})
```

Everything works nicely when testing with Postman.

The Problem occurs when I use server actions or client-side fetch call to the server with Next.js.

This is how I'm getting the user in my server action:

```
export const getUser = async () => {
 const userCookie = cookies().get("_session");
 const rawSession: any = userCookie?.value;
 const decodeRawSession = decodeURIComponent(rawSession);

 if (!rawSession) return [];
 const sessionId = cookieParser.signedCookie(decodeRawSession, String(process.env.REDIS_SECRET) || "secret");
 const session = await redis.get(`shub:${sessionId}`);
 if (!session) return [];
 const user = (session as any).passport.user;
 console.log('user from action', user)
 return user;
}
```

Without doing the decodeURIComponent the session isn't working.

I'm fine with doing that but lately I had some client-side code that required fetching on the client and this is how it looks like:

```
const followedCategories = await fetch(`http://localhost:3005/categories/search/${search}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
      const data = followedCategories ? await followedCategories.json() : [];
```

When including the credentials, I get the cookie in the header but without decoding it on the server the req.isAuthenticated() function always returns false in the middleware.

The only solution i found so far is to decode the request cookie on the server like so:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const { headers: { cookie } } = req;
  if (cookie) {
    const allCookies = cookie.split(';').map(c => {
      if (!c.startsWith('_session')) return c;
      return `_session=${decodeURIComponent(c.split('=')[1])}`
    });
    req.headers.cookie = allCookies.join('; ');
    next();
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
})
```

This works fine but it feels like a hack and like I definitely feel like I shouldn't be doing this.
Other methods I tried was adding `encode: (v) => v` within app.use(session({}) in the cookie
but it didn't work.

Any explanations or ideas as to why I have to do this or what I might be doing wrong are welcomed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205195/should-cookie-values-be-url-encoded

Comment: This answer gives some insights but It doesn't answer my question regarding how I can solve my problem without using the hack solution I've found