# Pass a clean cookie variable in Javascript / Vue JS

Tags: javascript, url, cookies, vuejs2

My scenario is this.

I have the following variable:

```
_s.$cookie.set('videoURL', this.sample_url)
```

Now, when I looked into Chrome dev tools on Application -> Cookies, this is what I see.

[image]

As you may see, there is special characters in between the URLs, probably replacing the "/".

How do you clean this such that is passes a clean URL (eg. http://helloworld.com)?

UPDATE:

After the first answer below, I revised my code. However the same special characters still exist.

my code now is as follows. I'm using Vue JS.

```
  urlEncoded = encodeURIComponent('http://helloworld.com')
  decodeURL = decodeURIComponent(urlEncoded)
  _s.$cookie.set('videoURL', decodeURL)
```

UPDATE 2

After passing the cookie variable to class variable, finally saw that the URL is now clean of special characters.

```
  _s.videoURL = _s.$cookie.get('videoURL')
  console.log(_s.videoURL)
```

Comment: Encode/Decode the value, and do note, you can't store it as _a clean url_ since it has characters that aren't allowed in a cookie. Is there a reason why you bother how it looks in the cookie?

Comment: You can parse them and deparse them wherever you are using them

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969232/476

Comment: @LGSon I'm trying to cached a video URL across different pages of the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store it as *a clean url* since it has characters that aren't allowed in a cookie.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie
- [Allowed characters in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies)

---

An option is to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) / [decode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) the value when write/read the cookie

```js
var url = "http://helloworld.com"
var url_encoded = encodeURIComponent(url)

console.log(url_encoded)

console.log(decodeURIComponent(url_encoded))
```

---

Updated after question edit, Vue JS is being used.

Here is two addons for Vue that might solve it for you

- https://github.com/alfhen/vue-cookie
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-localstorage

---

And as commented, to cached a video URL across different pages of the website, `localStorage` might be more appropriate.

Comment: This works in JSFiddle but applying this to my code still prompts the same output. I think I should note that I'm using Vue JS.

Comment: @vishnu And you can't do `encodeURIComponent(this.sample_url)` ?

Comment: @vishnu And if not, will this help: https://github.com/alfhen/vue-cookie

Comment: @vishnu Or maybe `localStorage`, as it doesn't have the same issue a cookie has when it comes to allowed characters: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-localstorage

Comment: @vishnu Added those two addons to my answer as well

Comment: updated my question with my updated code. Same error exists

Comment: @vishnu Well, you won't ever be able to have the value in the cookie to look clean, only so you know. Please provide how you read a cookie as well with Vue and I'll add a sample to answer how it should be, as what you did is not correct.