# Writing cookie seems to lose its original value

Tags: javascript, http, httpcookie

I seem to be having trouble storing a cookie and then reading back its value.

The cookie I'm writing is Name = `TransloadingInventory-filter`, Value = `Consignee:HALLIBURTON ENERGY SERVICES::ProductCategory:1::Product:2`.

But as soon as I write this value, the browser shows the current value for this cookie is `Consignee:::ProductCategory:::Product:`.

In addition, I don't know if this is related but when I try and read the `Request.Form` in ASP.NET, I get the exception `Incorrect Content-Type:`.

Is there an issue putting colons in cookie values? Can someone suggest some troubleshootng steps? Here's the function I'm using to write the cookie.

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = ';'
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + expires + '; path=/';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided works for me in Chrome with `setCookie('TransloadingInventory-filter', 'Consignee:HALLIBURTON ENERGY SERVICES::ProductCategory:1::Product:2', 1)`.

Further, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969339 references (and includes source material for) which characters are valid in cookie names/values which includes `:`.

Regarding incorrect content-type, check the network tab in debugger (or if you have access to the raw HTTP request) to see if a content-type header is being sent.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Edge and don't have Chrome on this computer. Hard to believe Edge can't handle this cookie value.