# When cookie has some values, it cannot be read back

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, cookies

When I save a cookie with the following value, it works fine:

`TransloadingInventoryFilter=Product:2`

When I save a cookie with the following value, it works fine:

`TransloadingInventoryFilter=ProductCategory:1::Product:2`

But when I save a cookie with the following value, it doesn't work:

`TransloadingInventoryFilter=Consignee:HALLIBURTON ENERGY SERVICES::ProductCategory:1::Product:2`

My browser correctly shows this as the cookie value. But when my page loads, `Request.Form` throws an `InvalidOperationException`: `Incorrect Content-Type:` .

And the `Request.Cookies` collection has all my cookies except `TransloadingInventoryFilter`, which is missing.

The following cookie value also does not work:

`TransloadingInventoryFilter=Consignee:HALLIBURTON ENERGY SERVICES`

I've spent hours on this issue. I cannot understand why this one cookie value does not work. And I don't know what else to try.

Note that I'm reading cookies using ASP.NET, but I'm writing my cookies using JavaScript and the following function.

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = ';'
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + expires + '; path=/';
}
```

Can anyone offer some suggestions?

Comment: Possibly the spaces in your value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/what-are-allowed-characters-in-cookies

Comment: @kevmc: Yes, that was it. Many thanks for helping me past that. I had no idea you can't have spaces in the value. If you want to put it in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spaces are not allowed in cookie values, refer to this question [What are allowed characters in cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/what-are-allowed-characters-in-cookies) for more details