# Servlet failed to addCookie

Tags: java, jsp, cookies, servlets

I'm a new bird learning Servlet. When I use cookie in Servlet, I found cookie can't be added after visiting web page.
Here's my code:

```java
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.Cookie;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class LastAccessServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        String lastAccessTime = null;
        Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        for (int i = 0; cookies != null && i < cookies.length; ++i){
            if ("lastAccess".equals(cookies[i].getName())) {
                lastAccessTime = cookies[i].getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (lastAccessTime == null){
            writer.println("Your first visit.");
        } else {
            writer.println("Last time" + lastAccessTime);
        }
        String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(new Date());
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("lastAccess", currentTime);
        cookie.setMaxAge(999999999);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        resp.addCookie(cookie);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Here's my WebPage:

[image]

No matter how many times I refresh, reload or change browsers, the result is the same.

I check the cookies in my edge browser.

[image]

The cookie hasn't the value name `lastAccess` I added, so I think the problem is in `resp.addCookie(cookie);`.But don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I'd say the problem is the cookie path. Browsers normally won't accept root level cookies for security/tracking reasons. The Javadoc on `setPath()` states: "A cookie's path mustinclude the servlet that set the cookie"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not actually with the code/logic but data here. You are trying to set a cookie value which is more like a Date string looking like `2022-10-01 03:01:22`.
**The cookie value here is illegal**. As per the [RFC6265](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt), you are not allowed to have some of the special characters in the cookie. A more detailed description is available with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969339/995052)

You can solve it by changing may be the way you form the cookie value. For eg use the timestamp instead of date string. Like below.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        String lastAccessTime = null;
        Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        for (int i = 0; cookies != null && i < cookies.length; ++i){
            if ("lastAccess".equals(cookies[i].getName())) {
                lastAccessTime = cookies[i].getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (lastAccessTime == null){
            writer.println("Your first visit.");
        } else {
            writer.println("Last time" + new Date(Long.parseLong(lastAccessTime)));
        }
        String currentTime = String.valueOf( new Date().getTime());
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("lastAccess", currentTime);
        cookie.setMaxAge(999999999);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        resp.addCookie(cookie);
    }
```

Comment: Thx! Your reply solved my problem bothering me for days.