# Saving '&' sign in Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to store the value `AFRSUSERNAME=v@r.com&AFRSPASSWORD=%&v~lyHYNrTCcQq6` into `Cookies["AFRSSTATION"]`. The value is saved successfully and i can see it using browser. Problem in accessing the values. When i try to get the value of  `returningUser["AFRSUSERNAME"]` i got  `v@r.com` and value of `returningUser["AFRSPASSWORD"]` is `%`. It looks like internal function spliting the value on the bases of `&` sign.  My question is how can i save the & sign in Cookie. Given bellow is related code

```
HttpCookie returningUser = null;

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["AFRSSTATION"] != null)
            {
                returningUser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["AFRSSTATION"];
                if (returningUser["AFRSUSERNAME"] != null &&
                    returningUser["AFRSUSERNAME"] != "" &&
                    returningUser["AFRSPASSWORD"] != null &&
                    returningUser["AFRSPASSWORD"] != "")
                {
                    UserName = returningUser["AFRSUSERNAME"];
                    Password = returningUser["AFRSPASSWORD"];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Broken string in cookie after ampersand (javascript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125807/broken-string-in-cookie-after-ampersand-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all [characters are allowed in Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies), you can use [Server.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [UrlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode(v=vs.110).aspx) methods to achieve this:-

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("AFRSSTATION");
cookie.Values.Add("AFRSUSERNAME", Server.UrlEncode("v@r.com"));
cookie.Values.Add("AFRSPASSWORD", Server.UrlEncode("%&v~lyHYNrTCcQq6"));
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

//Retrieve Cookie values
UserName = Server.UrlDecode(returningUser["AFRSUSERNAME"]);
Password = Server.UrlDecode(returningUser["AFRSPASSWORD"]);
```