# asp.net and cookies special characters

Tags: asp.net, cookies

Have found very interesting issue in asp.net with cookies:
when adding cookie with value like test&
using

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("test", "test&");
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

and then trying to retrieve value Request.Cookies["test"] trailing ampersand is lost. If it is not trailing it is not lost. In firebug or javascript data is correct so it is asp.net specific I think.
Of course mostly could say just use UrlEncode. But is it really necessary? Is there any list of disallowed charters for cookies (because I think it is smaller than for URLs)?
I have found similar topic but there is no & symbol in restricted list:
[Allowed characters in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies)

Answer (score 5):

The ampersand is not an allowed character in a cookie. It's necessary to encode the cookie data with the [`UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) method.

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cookie);
```

See also these SO questions/answers:

- [Broken string in cookie after ampersand (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125807/broken-string-in-cookie-after-ampersand-javascript)
- [How do you use an Ampersand in an HTTPCookie in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833176/how-do-you-use-an-ampersand-in-an-httpcookie-in-vb-net)