# Deserialize JSON string with & using JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, json, cookies, serialization

I have a JSON string stored in a cookie that has a `&` character in it:

```
{"Description":"The Livewire TS+ unlocks your vehicle's hidden performance by re-calibrating your vehicle's computer for Maximum Horsepower & Torque, Increased Throttle Response, Firmer Shifts and even Increased Fuel Mileage.","Sku":"SCTLWTSP","Count":1}
```

When I try to deserialize it, it throws an error about an illegal character.  I have narrowed this down to the `&` character.  I got around this by doing `.Replace("&","%26")`, but this stores the value back in the cookie with `%26`.

What is the best way to handle the `&` or any other character that might be a problem?  I am trying to keep the original string (not encoded) in the cookie.

I have tried `Html.Encode`, but this causes more illegal character problems when deserializing and I have tried `Uri.EscapeDataString`, but this did nothing.

To put some context this:

When the user `clicks add to cart`, it adds a `serialized object to a cookie`.  When they click add to cart again, I `deserialize the JSON string` so I can update the `Count` variable, but this is when the error happens because of the `&` character?

I have a custom class `ShoppingCartItem`, I am storing an array of `ShoppingCartItem` in the cookie.  Here is some code:

This is when I want to read the cookie string back into a `List<ShoppingCartItem>`

```
List<ShoppingCartItem> shoppingCartItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ShoppingCartItem>>(shoppingCartCookie["ShoppingCartItems"]);
```

When I write to the cookie, I use:

```
shoppingCartCookie["ShoppingCartItems"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(shoppingCartItems);
```

Json array example:

```
ShoppingCartItems=[{"Name":"X4 Performance Programmer ","ShortDescription":"The X4 Power Flash arrives Pre-Loaded with DYNO Proven tune files that INCREASE HORSEPOWER and TORQUE! ","Sku":"SCTX4","Count":1},{"Name":"Livewire TS Plus","ShortDescription":"The Livewire TS+ unlocks your vehicle's hidden performance by re-calibrating your vehicle's computer for Maximum Horsepower & Torque, Increased Throttle Response, Firmer Shifts and even Increased Fuel Mileage.","Sku":"SCTLWTSP","Count":1}]
```

Here is the exact line and error:

The error happens when this line is executed:

```
shoppingCartItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ShoppingCartItem>>(shoppingCartCookie["ShoppingCartItems"]);
```

The error is:

`Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path '[1].ShortDescription', line 1, position 359.`

Comment: I would imagine using the same library's serialization function would give the best results for a string that deserializes to the original.

Comment: @chris - I am doing that. I am calling `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` when saving the string to the cookie and when I want to get the object back out, I use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

Comment: What _type_ are you trying to deserialize to?  Please include some code.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez - Hi, I added some code, hopefully that helps. Thanks

Comment: The json you provided is a single object, but you're trying to deserialize that to a _list_ of objects?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez - Sorry, I just put that sample because that was the one causing the problem, I will put a better example.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez -  I updated the post with an array that is in my cookie

Comment: @xaisoft, I see. AFAICT, & is valid in a JSON string without being escaped. For me, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("&"))` produces `"&"`.

Comment: @chris - When I serialize the shopping cart item for the first time, it works, but when I want to add it a second time and deserialize the items first that contain the &, I get the error.  It only goes away when I remove the & or replace it.

Comment: @xaisoft please provide the line of code you get the error on. And the exact error message. It usually helps if you can provide a tiny program that demonstrates your issue. Certainly, the error you're getting doesn't have anything to do with json serialization -- & is nothing special as far as json is concerned.

Comment: Yes, a [mcve] would go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

I think, most likely, your issue isn't directly related to json serialization, but it is related to the fact that `&` isn't a valid character to put in a cookie (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5639729/201088)).

You will have to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`. E.g.:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList);
var cookieString = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(json);
// write cookie
...
// later when reading the cookie
var cookieString = ...
var json = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(cookieString);
var myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ShoppingCartItem>>(json);
```

Comment: Hi,  I think you may be right, I haven't tested your solution out yet, but I did notice when I added other key/value pairs in my cookie, they were separated by the &, so it does seem like a valid character, but I wonder if having it in my JSON string, it is being treated like a separator instead of the literal character.  I have updated my code with the exact line of the error and the error message.  I will try your solution and let you know how it goes. Thanks again.