# MVC set cookie not getting full string

Tags: cookies, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

My cookie will not set the full string "A&B".  When I request it, I only get 
"A".  Do I need to wrap it with something so it reads the "&", as I wonder if this character is breaking it.

controller:

```
Response.Cookies["Order"]["PrincId"] = model.Princ_ID.ToString();
```

view:

```
var session_princid = Request.Cookies["Order"]["PrincId"];
@session_princid
```

Comment: Try @Html.Raw(session_princid)

Comment: nope.  that didn't work.

Comment: maybe wrap the model.Princ_ID.ToString()  in something?

Comment: Yes, because it saves to my database before I set cookie and in the database it says "A&B"

Comment: I am using MVC5, when I replace with "A&B", I just get  "A".  I have tried using something else and it works with other values like "ABC".  For some reason it does not like '&' sign.

Comment: Answer found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833176/how-do-you-use-an-ampersand-in-an-httpcookie-in-vb-net?lq=1